# MediaRecorder throws exception when start is called

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

the below code throws an error when start is called:

```
                _recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                _recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
                _recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
                _recorder.SetProfile(CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.High));
                _recorder.SetOutputFile(FileName);
                _recorder.SetMaxDuration(10000);
                _recorder.Prepare();
                _recorder.Start();
```

The error message always seems to be the following:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: start failed.   
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <25999cc1fde6426b852c2e027711c254>:0    
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <25999cc1fde6426b852c2e027711c254>:0   
at Android.Media.MediaRecorder.Start () [0x0000a] in <7a2bbe1fcaec4467930361ae212aeea9>:0    
at MobileTwo.Droid.Services.AndroidCamera.InitializeCamera () [0x00120] in C:\GitRepositories\mobile-two\MobileTwo\MobileTwo.Droid\Services\AndroidCamera.cs:198
    --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace --- 
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.   
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)     
at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.InnerGestureListener.n_onSingleTapUp(Native Method)  
at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.InnerGestureListener.onSingleTapUp(InnerGestureListener.java:79)
at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:635)
at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.VisualElementRenderer_1.n_onTouch(Native Method)     
at md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.VisualElementRenderer_1.onTouch(VisualElementRenderer_1.java:66)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9296)     
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
```

at

> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md5b60ffeb829f638581ab2bb9b1a7f4f3f.PlatformRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(PlatformRenderer.java:55)
>       at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
>       at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
>     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2771)  at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
>     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
>     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9520)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
>     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
>     at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
>     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)    at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) }

I checked and I have the correct manifest permissions for this.  Any idea what else could be misconfigured? (I am debugging using a Nexus 7 tablet)

Edit: This is my manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Its failing on `InitializeCamera()` so the assumption would be you are not requesting camera permission

Comment: Updated with manifest

Comment: What API version is on that tablet?

Comment: It's Android 6.0 (API Version 23)

Comment: In Marshmallow and above you have to request camera permission at runtime:  https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: I believe I already am, I call `CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Camera)` and `CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Microphone)` and both return `PermissionStatus.Granted`.  I am guessing this is static across the app?